# Why does arr[3] yield different behavior from arr[SOME_CONST] where SOME_CONST = 3?

Tags: c

I am having a difficult time understanding why initializing an array with a literal size e.g. `int arr[3];`, yields a different behavior from an array initialized to a size of a constant like `int arr[SOME_CONST];` that is set to 3.

When the size of the array is provided as a literal, it behaves as expected:

```c
int arr[3];

//initialize the first two elements of the array, leave the third element uninitialized.
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;


//print all elements of array
printf("arr[0]: %d\n", arr[0]);
printf("arr[1]: %d\n", arr[1]);
printf("arr[2]: %d\n", arr[2]);
```

Output:

```
arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 2
arr[2]: 0
```

As you can see in the output the value of the uninitialized element `arr[2]` is `0` just as expected.

The behavior becomes unexpected when the array size is defined as a constant, like so:

```c
const int SOME_CONST = 3;
int arr[SOME_CONST];

//initialize the first two elements of the array, leave the third element uninitialized.
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;

//print all elements of array
printf("arr[0]: %d\n", arr[0]);
printf("arr[1]: %d\n", arr[1]);
printf("arr[2]: %d\n", arr[2]);
```

Output:

```
arr[0]: 1
arr[1]: 2
arr[2]: 32766
```

Now the uninitialized element `arr[2]` has a seemingly random value of `32766`

Could someone help me understand why the two cases behave differently.

I've created two snippets on ideone to demonstrate this behavior as well.

[Expected](https://ideone.com/vszmQb)

[Unexpected](https://ideone.com/jhfZrO)

Comment: Are these arrays allocated local to a function, or globally?

Comment: Both snippets are inside of `main`.

Comment: regarding: `printf("arr[2]: %d\n", arr[2]);`  since the `arr[2]` element of `int arr[3];` is not initialized, the code contains undefined behavior.  here is the message from the compiler: *untitled2.c:15:2: warning: ‘arr[2]’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]*  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the messages about warnings

Comment: Since the `arr[2]` entry is not initialized, the call to `printf()` will display what ever trash is in memory at that location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C standard does not guarantee initialization of local variables.

Regarding the initialization statements:

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
```

Compiler can very well optimize them to this statement:

```
int arr[3] = {1, 2, 0};
```

But then I would not rely on one compilers behavior for such scenarios. Better would be to be explicit in the initialization statements.

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152138/local-variable-initialized-to-zero-in-c/21152256) for similar discussion.

Also in the second scenario you are trying to use Variable Length Arrays: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array

Which is an extension provided by GCC Compiler you are using, and I would not recommend using them in your projects.

The length of the array is computed at run-time and probably allocated on stack(depends on compiler implementation).

So it is not explicitly initialized in the code.

You can see the example here for the generated code: https://godbolt.org/z/J_JEVe

Answer (score 3):

> We shouldn't bother how compiler is behaving in certain cases unless
>   it is incorrect as per standard.

As per C standard, the uninitialized local variables can have any garbage value. Better to initialize them and don't be dependent on compiler.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler/system do you use? Maybe put your const value outside the main function. Normally both result in arbritary values taken from the stack.

Comment: This is the compiler version line: `gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC)`

Comment: I tried your code on my system. In both cases I get different results on every execution. So don't rely on that it is zero'ed. I tried gcc-7 gcc-8 and gcc-10.