# Can't set second element of an empty string in C

Tags: c, string

I have this code, which doubles every letter in `nabucco`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
        char string1[20] = "nabucco";
        char string2[40];
        int j=-1;
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(string1);i++){
                j++;
                string2[j]   = string1[i];
                j++;
                string2[j] = string1[i];
        }
        printf("string1=\t%s\n",string1);
        printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2);
}
```

`string2` is set to and prints `nnaabbuuccccoo`.

However, when I try to set `j=0;` `string2` prints (and is presumably set to) nothing.

If `j=0` before going into the loop, then j is incremented to 1 in the `for` loop, which starts off setting the second element of the empty `string2`. Is there something behind the scenes preventing any element other than the first from being set? I do not understand what is causing this behavior.

Comment: How did you determine that elements other than the first weren't set? I don't see any code to output them. Did you use a debugger?

Comment: I guess that `string2[0]` is equal to `0` or `\0`. The format specifier `%s` prints until it encounters `\0`. Just remove the first incrementation and place after the second assignment.

Comment: `string2` is uninitialized, meaning it can contain any value in position `0`, including a null terminator character.  When `printf` prints strings, it stops at the first null terminator that it sees.

Comment: you're "lucky" that it printed `nnaabbuuccccoo` and stopped, since you never `NUL` terminate `string2`.

Comment: and just FYI, you can get rid of `j` entirely and do `string2[i*2] = string1[i]; string2[i*2+1] = string1[i];`

Comment: If you want to see what's actually in the array after the loop, add this: `for (i=0;i<40;i++) printf("%d\n",string[i]&0xff);`

Comment: Aftrr the loop do: `string2[j + 1] = 0;` to properly terminate the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program as posted has undefined behavior since you don't put a null terminator in `string2`.

If you start with `j=0`, you never set the value of `string2[0]` since you increase `j` before using it, so that position remains indeterminable.

Possible fix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
        char string1[20] = "nabucco";
        char string2[40];

        size_t j=0;
        for(size_t i=0, len = strlen(string1); i<len; i++) {
            string2[j++] = string1[i];  // increase j "after" using the current value
            string2[j++] = string1[i];
        }
        string2[j] = '\0';                     // add null terminator

        printf("string1=\t%s\n",string1);
        printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2);
}
```

An alternative could be to initialize `string2` when you create it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
        char string1[20] = "nabucco";
        char string2[40] = {0};           // zero initialized

        for(size_t i=0, j=0, len = strlen(string1); i<len; i++) {
            string2[j++] = string1[i];
            string2[j++] = string1[i];
        }

        printf("string1=\t%s\n",string1);
        printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2);
}
```

Comment: `unsigned` is not the correct index type. It should be `size_t` or `ssize_t`

Comment: @0___________ True. Lazyness. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You increment the counter before using it the first time, so if you set `j=0` you do `j++` before using it first, which means you start with `string2[1]`.

You can change it like so:

```
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(string1);i++){
            string2[j]   = string1[i];
            j++;
            string2[j] = string1[i];
            j++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2);
```

and `string2` was set from the second character, this is a sort of undefined behaviour (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152138/local-variable-initialized-to-zero-in-c)). `string2[0]` was not initialised, and could contain *anything* (from sensitive data to something that can't be parsed successfully by other functions - okay, here it is a single character; in other circumstances it could be more than that, if you started with `j=20` for example). Which is why undefined behaviour is to be avoided at all costs.

In this case, the quirks of platform, compiler and process made it so the first character is a zero. Since C strings are zero-terminated, and `string2` *begins* with a zero, `printf` prints nothing. If you printed something like this, where "." is a 0 character (ASCII 0),

```
 "nnaa.bbuuccoo."
```

you would get only "nnaa". By the same token, printf'ing ".nnaabbuuccoo" gets you nothing.

If you were to print `string2` starting at the *second* character, you'd get different results:

```
printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2 + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

After the for loop the character array `string2` does not contain a string because you forgot to append it with the terminating zero character `'\0'`. So this call of `printf`

```
printf("string2=\t%s\n",string2);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

A simplest approach to resolve the problem is to initialize the array in its declaration. For example

```
char string2[40] = "";
```

As for this statement

> However, when I try to set j=0; string2 prints (and is presumably set
> to) nothing.

then within the for loop the variable `j` is at once incremented.

```
    int j = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen(string1);i++){
            j++;
            string2[j]   = string1[i];
            //...
```

So the first character of the array `string2` is not set.

In this case it is better to write the for loop the following way

```
    size_t j = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( string1 ); i < n; i++ ){
            string2[j++] = string1[i];
            string2[j++] = string1[i];
    }

    string2[j] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because strings in C are null terminated. So when you set j=0 outside of loop, you skip setting first character which remains null.

Comment: >you skip setting first character which remains null.

It **happens** to be null in that case but it is actually undefined behaviour here. It can be null and can be anything else. And some compilers can do very unexpected things with this program.