# What is the lifetime of an object immediately passed as a parameter?

Tags: c++, memory, reference, lifetime, object-lifetime

I had some code that looked something like the following:

```
struct fooclass {
    char data[32];
}

fooclass makefoo() {
    fooclass res;
    // for example:
    memset(res.data, 0, sizeof(res.data));
    res.data[0] = 43;
    return res;
}

struct do_stuff {
    const fooclass& obj;
    do_stuff(const fooclass& obj_in) : obj(obj_in) { }

    void operate() { /* do things with obj; */ }
}

bool put_it_to_work(struct do_stuff& f) {
    f.operate();
    f.operate();
    return true;
}

bool call_it_all() {
    do_stuff local(makefoo());
    return put_it_to_work(local);
}
```

With gcc, the code worked fine. With MSVC2012, `local.obj` became corrupted.

The question is: how long does the `fooclass` returned by `makefoo` last? Should it be until the end of `call_it_all`, or is it just until the end of the `do_stuff local(makefoo())` line and I just got lucky? I'd appreciate a reference to the standard.

Comment: This code is broken -- `local` stores a reference to a temporary.

Comment: Until the end of the full-expression, 12.2/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
struct do_stuff {
    const fooclass& obj;
```

`obj` is a reference, not a proper object, so no copy is ever made of the result of `makefoo()`. The real object that `obj` references is destructed when the `local` object has finished being constructed, specifically when the anonymous temporary variable that `makefoo()` returns is destroyed.

I think you were just lucky that it worked under gcc. Perhaps the object that `obj` refered to *was* being destroyed as it should be, only its data was left in RAM and the program appeared to work properly. Perhaps MSVC was "erased" the RAM that `obj` referred to such that attempts to use it would fail quickly.

Comment: I thought the binding of a temporary to a const reference extended the lifetime of the temporary?

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary) which explained why the lifetime was not extended in this case or rather why the lifetime ends after the construction is completed.

Comment: Nice find, @JamesAdkison. Thanks for contributing it.

Comment: Does GCC implement anything like the [Visual Studio Magic Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)? I thought it could but that's probably what valgrind is for...

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, @nonsensickle. Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526602/is-there-a-gcc-flag-to-initialise-local-variable-storage).