# set default value for all uninitialized variables

Tags: c, cmake, c-preprocessor, safety-critical

I have [a legacy code](https://github.com/Foadsf/ElmerGrid) where there are like a zillion uninitialized

> warning C4100: : unreferenced formal parameter

or potentially uninitialized:

> warning C4701: potentially uninitialized local variable  used

variables, which can cause undefined behavior later down the line. Is there any way to tell the compiler to set all the uninitialized variables to something more debuggable like `NULL`. Probably using either of options

- preprocessing macros
- compiler options
- CMake options

For example, consider this dummy code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   int a;

   printf("%d\n",a);

   return 0;
}
```

I want to use either of the options above to set all cases like `a` to `NULL` or maybe in this case, `0` if `NULL` is not possible.

**P.S.** Here I'm using MSVC to catch the possible issues but in the end I want my solution to be cross platform and compiler agnostic. So compiler specific solutions (e.g., GCC, Clang...) are highly appreciated anyway.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: And how would that make it more debuggable anyway? If the compiler is pointing out the errors to you then the best thing to do is to go in and fix them. Blindly setting values to some default value may cause more harm than good as it may hide problems until it inevitably has a runtime error at the least convenient time.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to tell the compiler to do this. What I'd do [and have done similar in the past], is write a `perl/python` script that parses the compiler warnings and add an initializer to the declaration in the target source file (e.g. `char *ptr;` goes to `char *ptr = NULL;`). You could even make this interactive for some files and have the script ask a `y/n` question as to whether it should make the change.

Comment: @CraigEstey would you be kind to share your scripts? In general what tools are out there to automatize this sort of painful stuff?

Comment: `tell the compiler` - which compiler are you talking to?

Comment: @KamilCuk here I'm using MSVC to catch the possible issues. But in the end I hope my code to be cross-platform and compiler agnostic.

Comment: Cross platform is local variables have indeterminate value and if you want them to be initialized you should specify the initializer. As I was in the middle of researching an answer for gcc, you should modify your question, as the answer will be very compiler dependent. How is your question related to cmake? [This for gcc still holds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526602/is-there-a-gcc-flag-to-initialise-local-variable-storage). No, this is not possible with gcc without a custom [plugin](https://lwn.net/Articles/727320/).

Comment: @kaylum You are right. But for almost all of those zillion cases, a `0` initialization would suffice. Later I will add testing to the code base and I hope I can catch possible issues over there and edit the special cases then.

Comment: @KamilCuk would you be kind to provide the GCC specific solutions you have found? in the end, we can put everything together and have a compiler agnostic solution hopefully.

Comment: I have a framework [written in perl] for doing mass edits to source code [which has lots of safety checks] that is part of a much larger [too large] suite of tools I have. A single script isn't too difficult, just some regex to parse the error output and and then a rewrite of the target source. It only gets "interesting" if you have (e.g.) `char *ptr, *ptr2;` The script needs to have a "review" mode that just shows the changes without actually doing them. That way you "do no harm". I cloned your repo, did `cmake /home/src` but got `direct.h` No such file. I'm on linux, and this is MS?

Comment: @CraigEstey would you please try the `develop` branch [here](https://github.com/Foadsf/ElmerGrid/tree/develop)

Comment: @CraigEstey for the moment I'm using MSVC and MSYS2-MinGWw64, but next I will move to Linux and macOS hopefully.

Comment: I commented out `#include <direct.h>` but now `#include "metis.h"` reports the file is missing.

Comment: @CraigEstey true. I have not set the instructions for Linux but it METIS is available on almost all Linux repositories according to the [Repology](https://repology.org/project/metis/versions). and if you clone the latest develop branch you don't have to comment anything thing out, hopefully :)

Comment: If a variable is set to a default value wouldn't it technically be initialized already?

Comment: If this code has a lot of variables that are used before being initialized then, in all likelihood, this is the least of your problems. These are very simple things to get right first time. The fact that the original authors did not get something so simple correct is likely a good indication that there are lots of bugs in this code. You should plan accordingly. Set the compiler to treat warnings as errors, and fix every single one. Plan to spend time on reviewing and fixing this software.

Answer (score 4):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

I've cloned your develop repo.

Eventually, I was able to do a `make -i`. The output was about 500 lines [of errors].

So, there aren't enough errors to justify an automated script (i.e. by the time you get the script to production quality, you can do manual examination and fixup in less time).

And, some of the errors should be examined for logic errors, notably `-Wmaybe-unitialized`, which is what you were concerned with. Now might be a good time to determine if just changing: `int foobar;` into `int foobar = 0;` is okay. If so, that's what I'd do. (i.e.) If the code, based on the `if` hierarchy, never *actually* uses the value when it's uninitialized, adding `int foobar = 0;` just tells the compiler to STFU about a non-problem.

But, it *may* actually be a bug. *If* the code path the warning is complaining about *is* taken. Perhaps the code path hasn't shown up in practice, but, with different input data [in the future], the code *is* executed. This would be a [latent] bug.

At a minimum, just initializing with `= 0;` would change *unpredictable* random side effects into *predictable* side effects. If the function fails, it will now fail in a consistent/predictable way (vs. relying on the random value it gets in the [uninitialized] stack frame).

But, this would be a good time to desk check the code for [latent] bugs. You'll get more attaboys ;-)

A number of errors were `-Wunused-parameter`. Normally, I add `-Wno-unused-parameter` to `CFLAGS` if the code is *known* to be working. IMO, this really isn't even a bug [real, imaginary, or theoretical] most of the time--it's not an *error* to *not* use a parameter, just a warning for newbies writing new code. If you have a function signature that has an extra parameter that you have to keep for backwards compatibility, but the replacement function doesn't need it, you'll get a false positive here.

For `-Wunused-but-set-variable`, I'd remove the declaration *and* the assignment to it. Triage against `int result = important_function_that_changes_globals();`. There, *keep* the function call. Replace with: `important_function_that_changes_globals();`. Or, if you must [and, personally, I *never* do this]: `(void) important_function_that_changes_globals();`

But, there are others that indicate bugs (e.g.) `-Wstringop-truncation` which is indicative of [possible] buffer overflow.

The code base in the `src` subdirectory is [only] 30,000 lines. Again, with only about 500 lines of error messages.

Based on my experience, the errors could be triaged in 1-3 days [and one week max].

But, as *jarmod* pointed out, there may be more serious errors [that *only* show up with runtime debugging].